# How to call a variable in another file and dynamically change variable names? PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I have these two files, which are a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
FILE_1.py:

import FILE_2

class first(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        ...
        self.item1 = second("Apple", 0)
        self.item1.add()
        self.item2 = second("Banana", 1)
        self.item2.add()
        ...

FILE_2.py:

import FILE_1

class second(Object):
    def __init__(self, name, row):
        self.name = name
        self.row = row
    def add(self):
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.name)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, self.row, 0)
```

So I have two issues that I can't get past at the moment.

First, I'm having trouble calling self.gridLayout from `class first` to `class second`.  I can't move self.gridLayout because I have a third and a fourth... file that also require self.gridLayout. 
Second, how can I change the the self.label variable name dynamically so that the label operators do not overlap between objects.

Thanks.

Comment: That is not how classes work. If you want to use attributes of another class you have to inherit from it like so: `class A(object): blah` and then `class B(A): blah`

Comment: Does that also apply when they're not within the same file?

Comment: `from FILE_1 import first; class second(first)` will do that

Comment: Hmm... looks like I'm still getting a `'second' object has no attribute 'gridLayout'` error.

Comment: You are making circular references, you could overcome it by moving import inside __init__ methods, so they will be evaluated only during execution. But I recommend reconsider your class distribution across modules - it is most likely design issue - normally you should avoid circular references instead of solving import issue.

Comment: Do you mean I should move BOTH imports into the respective `__init__`? I wish I could avoid doing so but I have a main file, and multiple secondary files that actually utilize the main function's variables all together, then returns back to the main function... At this point I'm not sure how I could fix it to be honest :( EDIT1: I guess I could move all the secondary modules into the main file but I fear that it'll make things just too messy.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Illustrate the first and second questions with actual code (on SO code is worth a thousand words) that shows the problem what you're trying to do and what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your help, but I ended up coming up with a more simple... I don't know if more efficient, but working method.

Instead of having a circular reference, I just passed in whatever variable I needed from `FILE_1`.

```
FILE_1:
...
self.item1 = second("Apple", 0 , self.gridLayout)

FILE_2: 
...
def __init__(self, name, row, layout):
    ...
    self.layout = layout
def add(self):
    ...
    self.layout.addWidget(self.name, self.row, 0)
```

As for the second part of my issue, it ended up not being an issue in the end :)